# Setting ComputerName in unattend.xml

Tags: wds

I've got a WDS environment setup that has been working beautifully for a long time now. We want to make a small change to the way PC are named during the deployment phase. Currently, WDS automatically names the machine with the user name, and then some random characters.

```
USER-Q04352
```

This was fine, but we now would like to change it something like:

```
COMPANYNAME-Q04352
```

Can you use a text string, plus an asterisk in the unattend.xml file to get this behavior? So it would look similar to this:

```
<ComputerName>COMPANYNAME-*</ComputerName>
```

If not, what is a good way to do this? Are additional scripts required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WDS uses a COMPUTERNAME environment variable for managing how this is set up.

This is set on the deployment server properties, under the 'AD DS' tab. The 'Format' line is what dictates what the computer name will look like.

It sounds like you want to replace the `%Username-` with `COMPANYNAME-`

You can also use the unattend files to set this up as well, depending on your environment's complexity.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. I knew it was in there somewhere!